# JBoss 5.2 Asynchronous Support in Servlet 3.0

Tags: servlets, asynchronous, jboss

I am using JBoss 5.2 to run the web app with servlet that will do asynchronous http.
In my `web.xml` I have something like this:

```
<servlet>....


  <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

It works fine with Tomcat 7 but in Jboss it throws error...

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.startAsync()Ljavax/servlet/AsyncContext;

Could someone please help

Thanks

Comment: The error contains the answer to the problem. That you're unable to interpret it doesn't mean that it is worthless information. Please edit your question to include information about the error (the answer) so that we can explain it in layman's terms for you. By the way, what exactly makes you think that JBoss 5.2 supports Servlet 3.0? Where exactly in JBoss 5.2 specification/documentation is this mentioned? Did the error you got really not hint something about a possible incompatibility?

Comment: I got: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.startAsync()Ljavax/servlet/AsyncContext;

Comment: Look, there's no such method in `HttpServletRequest` implementation as provided by the target runtime (in this case, JBoss 5.2). As per the documentation, that method was introduced in Servlet 3.0. The target runtime in question is clearly not Servlet 3.0 compatible.

Comment: So how can I use servlet 3.0 in Jboss 5.2?

Comment: Just upgrade JBoss itself to a Servlet 3.0 compatible version.

Comment: That will be easy but we are required to stay at Jboss 5.2 !!!

Comment: Then it's end of story.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss didn't use the Servlet 3.0 Spec until JBoss 6.0.0 Came out, so it looks like you are out of luck in terms of making 5.2 use it. (Though I didn't think there was a 5.2 version of JBoss...)

But it looks like with Resteasy they found a way to provide a very simple callback API to provide asynchronous capabilities:

http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/Asynchronous_HTTP_Request_Processing.html#Asynch_HTTP_JBossWeb